# How to check if all substrings can be found in a dictionary

Tags: algorithm, search, substring

I have a problem that I want to solve as efficiently as possible. As an example,
I am given a string of words: `A B C D` and I have a 'dictionary' with 5 entries:

```
A
B C
B D
D
E
```

The dictionary tells me which substrings can be in my input string. And I want to check as efficiently as possible if the whole input string can be split into substrings so that all of them are found in the dictionary.

In the example the input string can be found by splitting it into `A`, `B C` and `D`

I'd like to know if there's a better way than just bruteforcing through all possible substrings. The less I check if a substring is in a dictionary the better.

It's not necessary to know which substrings couldn't be found in case there are no possible solutions.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use the same substring several time ?

Comment: An easy solution is build an trie tree using the dictionary, then match the string using the tree and get a set of end-point, then do the same thing from one of end-point, which is DFS, also memoize the result that whether could match to the end from end-point

Answer (score 1):

I would use a tree instead of a dictionary. This will improve the search speed and will eliminate sub-trees for searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the same substring several time, there is a natural dynamic programming solution to this.

Let n be the size of your string. Let v be a vector of size n such that v[i] = true if and only if the substring made of the (n-i) last character of your original string can be broken down with your dictionary. Then you can fill the vector v backwards, starting at the last index decreasing i at each step.

In pseudo-code :

```
Let D be your dictionnary
Let s be your string
Let n be the size of s
(Let s[i:j] denote the substring of s made by characters between i and j (inclusive))
Let v be a vector of size n+1 filled with zeros
Let v[n] = 1
For int i = n-1; i>=0; i--
    For int j = i; j <=n-1; j++
        If (s[i:j] is in D) and (v[j+1] is equal to 1)
            v[i] = 1
            Exit the for loop
Return v[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it run in `O(N^2)` by following method.

First store all your string in a trie.

Second, use dynamic programming approach to solve your problem. For each position `i` we will be calculating whether the substring of the first `i` symbols can be split into words from a dictionary (a trie). We will use, for simplicity, a forward-looking approach of dynamic programming.

So first we set that the substring of first `0` symbols can be split. Then we iterate from `0` to `N-1`. When we come to position `i`, we assume that we know the answer for this position already. If the split is possible, then we can go from this position and see which strings starting from this position are in the trie. For every such string, mark its end position as possible. By using the trie, we can do this in `O(N)` per one external loop iteration.

```
t = trie of given words
ans = {false}
ans[0] = true
for i=0..N-1
    if ans[i]   // if substring s[0]..s[i-1] can be split to given words
       cur = t.root
       for j=i to N-1    // go along all strings starting from position i
           cur=cur.child(s[j])   // move to the child in trie
            // therefore, the position cur corresponds to string
            // s[i]...s[j]
           if cur.isWordEnd    // if there is a word in trie that ends in cur
               ans[j+1] = true  // the string s[0]..s[j] can be split
your answer is in ans[N]
```

Total time is `O(N^2)`.